# Echo the ending part or last folder of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in PHP

Tags: php, explode, preg-split, document-root

I need to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to scandir for files and folders to display for my nav menu.

Let's say my root directory is at `/home/user/public_html/website/`.

Here's how I echo the root directory:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

it will display `/home/user/public_html/website/`

Here's how I echo a folder in the root directory:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'about/';
```

it will display `/home/user/public_html/website/about/`

**Question:** How can I strip everything that it displays all the way up to the root folder and/or sub-folder.

**Example**: If I echo `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, I want it to display as `/` instead of the entire `/home/user/public_html/website/` path.

and if I echo a sub-folder I want it to display as `/about/` instead of `/home/user/public_html/website/about/`.

So, how can I get it to echo just the ending part of the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` instead of the entire directory path?

I've tried `dirname` and `basename` but neither of those does what I need. I've thought of string replace but isn't there something much easier to add onto `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` that will just echo out the root folder or root folder plus sub-folder?

**Update**:

I ended up using the answer below from anant kumar singh but tweaking it using preg_split instead of explode because preg_split can take multiple string delimiters where as explode can take only 1.

```
$newArray = preg_split( " (-in/|-ca/|-co/) ", dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) );
if(count($newArray)>1){
    echo '/'.$newArray[1].'/';
    }else{
        echo '/';
    }
```

If you know of a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, please post your answers below.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Ya I've tried lots of things so far, but can't find anything yet. dirname, basename. Is there something else out there besides these two?

Comment: ^ 1. Add your attempts/work into your question! 2. Take a look at `explode()`

Comment: it's confusing. once you say ending part of document root and on the other side you say that for root folder you want to display /? can you please differentiate it? and you wan to just echo it or gona use for some other purpose?

Comment: as apposed to echoing the full path `/home/user/public_html/website/` where /website/ is the folder of the root, I instead want to echo out `/` which is the last trailing slash after the folder website. But if I'm echoing out a sub-directory like the about page `/home/user/public_html/website/about/`, I instead want it to display as `/about/`.

Comment: So why not simply use the single `/`? Basically what you're writing means `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should stand for a constant `/`?! Then simply use that. As in: `echo '/about/';`

Comment: it is not that simple. I have to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. I can't echo `/` because it has to come from `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` not my own string.

Comment: well then `$x = substr($yourStringIncludingDocRoot, strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) - 1);` But still I don't get it. The way you use it (even if forced) is fully redundant this way.

Comment: The reason I need to use it is because I'm using a navigation menu based on directory. The script is included on each page. It creates the menu nav with the tabs. Each tab represents each folder in the root directory. If I use `../` instead of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, then the linking will not be correct on the menu if inside a sub-folder. If you want to see the full script let me know and I'll create a fiddle to show you. I'm sure it is not the best way to do it and perhaps you can critique it.

Comment: If you can provide a semi-runnable sample, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: please up-vote the answer also. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with explode in the following manner:--

```
$newArray = explode('website/',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
 if(count($newArray)>1){
   echo "/".$newArray[1];
}else{
    echo '/';
}
```

**As you already said that preg_split is done the job for you:-**

```
$newArray = preg_split( " (-in/|-ca/|-co/) ", dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) ); if(count($newArray)>1){ echo "/".$newArray[1]."/"; }else{ echo '/'; }
```

NOTE:- Don't be panic.I am not going to take your credit. I just did it for the future peoples purpose. If you put it as an answer then i will remove it.

Comment: I tweaked your answer a bit and used preg_split as I need to explode on more than one delimiter.

Comment: you can put your answer here and marked that. it will help others to find ther solution.

Comment: I tweaked your answer a bit because explode can not take more than 1 string delimiter but preg_split can take multiple. `$newArray = preg_split( " (-in/|-ca/|-co/) ", dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) );
  if(count($newArray)>1){
   echo "/".$newArray[1]."/";
   }else{
    echo '/';
    }`